# How to push multiple inserts or updates together in one single db hit - for a multi DB (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL) App

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-injection, database-performance

I am trying to develop a **Data Layer Library** for our project that **supports multiple databases** (**SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL** at this point). The database servers more often than not will be hosted in a **public cloud**. Data Access (select, insert, update, delete) are performed from a windows forms client as well as a web server. The winforms Client forces me to design stuff in such a way that minimal db round trips are made.

The problem I have is '**how to push multiple inserts or updates together in one single db hit**'.

I have done lot of google'ing and research on this and know that parametrized inserts/updates are the way to go keeping in mind SQL injection attacks. But it is not suitable for me as I don't want multiple round trips to the db.

BulkCopy is SQL Server specific and used for mostly for inserts.

Stored Procedures/XML - I have different databases which makes it hard and difficult to maintain stored procs for each one of them. And also the number of tables are not static, new table may be introduced any time or existing tables altered as the application is very dynamic in nature.

The best option for me looks like (at this point) is to concat sql strings (using StringBuilder of course) and fire the query at one shot. I looked at **owasp-esapi-dotnet library** (http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-dotnet/) but sql encoding (to prevent sql injection) is not implemented. Also the project looks dead now (last commit was in Dec 2010).

Are there any open source implementations taking care of SQL injection for multiple databases (at least SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL)?

Is there any other way I can get this goal achieved (multiple inserts/updates in a single db round trip)?

I am using C# on .NET 4.

EDIT: We are trying to roll this out as a product where the client will have an opportunity to pick/choose which ever DB vendor he/she wants.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am using C#.NET.

Comment: It looks like you've already examined and discarded the common solutions to this problem (i.e., an application server, a stored proc, or restricting yourself to one DB vendor).  I think you'll have to decide if rolling your own solution on the application end that can account for SQL injection itself is significantly more or less complex than maintaining the code with stored procedures.  I vaguely recall having problems with multiple statements in the CommandText of SqlClient, but it's been too long for me to remember.

Comment: @BaconBits: We are trying to roll this out as a product where the client will have an opportunity to pick/choose which ever DB vendor he wants.

Comment: You could do this by moving all the record opertations up to a service on your database. Build a file and load it for instance most DBMS's have a version of that. Big question you need to answer on any bulk update/ insert though, is reconcilliation.

Comment: I understand that. My point is that you've already discarded the common solutions I'm aware of. So no matter what you do, you have to code your own thing. Is it going to be easier to code and maintain something that processes on the client but is more vulnerable to injection, or code and maintain an sproc on the server that is more difficult to code and maintain?

Comment: @BaconBits: It is not that I have rejected the common solutions. I just wanted to share all the assessment we have done already, and what we feel about it. We are still far from zero'ing in one approach.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Reconciliation is gonna be tough for us.

Comment: Hard to say from here which way you should go. All I can say if you choose to address a generic bulk insert/ update yourself, it's going to cost and possibly big. Me'd be saying to myself, isa lot of round trips based on all the other constraints, that big a problem. Prototype the traffic, get some metrics, maybe you are being premature?

Comment: If it is, I think I'd be going with plugin middleware optimised for each backend you want to support, instead of one generic mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If this was my problem, I'd set up linked servers on sql server.  Then I'd write stored procedures that accept the necessary parameters from your applications and process them.

Comment: I fail to see how a linked server can help to "*push multiple updates in a single query*". Especially with Oracle or Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think he was under the impression that the DB would be one application instance across multiple DB platforms rather than multiple instances each on any possible DB platform.

Comment: multiple instances each on any possible DB platform - this is correct.

Comment: @BaconBits: ah. I thought it should be a DBMS independent solution that uses as few statements as possible to store rows in a single DBMS.